# Procedure or function 'spGetCountryByNames' expects parameter '@countryName', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is happening when I call a SQL Server stored procedure with a parameter through .net, even though I am supplying the parameter.

Here is my my stored procedure code:

```
create procedure spGetCityByNames
    @cityName char(10)
as
begin
    select * 
    from tblCity
    where cityName like @cityName + '%'
end
```

and my .net code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetCityByNames", con);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cityName", TextBox1.Text + "%");

con.Open();
GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
GridView1.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Show your `spGetCountryByNames` procedure, not `spGetCityByNames`. Error message points on _that_ procedure. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] as a start..

Comment: what about using varchar(10) ?

Comment: Sorry, i tried it with countries first then by cities..

Comment: error msg: Procedure or function 'spGetCityByNames' expects parameter '@cityName', which was not supplied

Comment: also i checked spGetCityByNames 'd%' is returning NULL even though cities are listed with 'd' alphabet ..why is that??

Comment: @neha Please add some data-set on which you're running this like query. Also put the complete stack-trace of the exception you get.

Comment: "sp" does not stand for "stored procedure" it stands for "Special Procedure", if you prefix your procedures with sp it modifies themail way they can be called. Custom procedures used in a single database should not start with sp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code line `%` is unnecessary since you already having that included in your procedure code `where cityName like @cityName + '%'`. It should just be

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cityName", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
```

Also, try using `VARCHAR` instead of `CHAR` and use `cmd.Parameters.Add()` method instead of `AddWithValue()`

Change your proc code to have `VARCHAR` like

```
create procedure spGetCityByNames
@cityName varchar(10)
as
begin
    select * from tblCity
    where cityName like @cityName + '%'
end
```

In code behind have

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@cityName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
```

**EDIT:**

Per comment from @fabio, No it's not entire refactoring of code. What I guessed and the reason I modified both the procedure and used `Add()` function is:

OP had pamameter as `char(10)` type column and was using `AddWithValue()` method. `AddWithValue()` has a drawback that it has to infer the type of the parameter on fly and mostly it will infer the type as `nvarchar` since the data is coming from a textbox control. To my guess, something was going weird there and so the problem surfacing.

I know my guess/explanation doesn't matches with the exact error message and it was a calculated guess but look what, it worked as I expected.

Comment: @Rahul, can you explain reason why "Missing parameter" exception was thrown, even parameter with same name was added? Your answer seems more like refactoring of OP's code

Comment: @Fabio, no it wasn't entirely. See edit in answer if that helps.